# MySQL from OSX Terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

I seem to be missing something as all of the tutorials that show how to run MySQL from OSX's command line aren't working.

I can turn the MySQL Server status on and off via System preferences, but if I follow one of the tutorial that shows how to run from the command line  using `sudo mysqld_safe` it returns the `sudo: mysqld: command not found`

I've also tried logging into MySQL using `mysql -u root -p` and I get `bash: mysql: command not found`

`/usr/local/mysql/bin/` does exist I just feel like something wasn't installed properly on the client side.  Any help figuring out how to access mysql from the terminal would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`/usr/local/mysql/bin` is not in the default `$PATH`. `$PATH` is the list of directories that are searched when you try to use an executable without specifying a complete path.

You either need to use the full path (`/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_executable_here`) or add it to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
```

**For macOS Mojave and earlier**

You can add this line to a file called `.profile` in your home directory to execute it each time you create a new shell:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

**For macOS Catalina and later**

Starting with `macOS Catalina`, Mac devices use `zsh` as the default login shell and interactive shell and you have to update `.zprofile` file in your home directory.

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"' >> ~/.zprofile
source ~/.zprofile
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

Comment: i used `sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe and that turned it on the server.  I still can;'t figure out how to log into the client though.

Comment: i got it. I had to use `sudo ./bin/local/mysql -u root -p`  Is there an easier way to do this, or do I have to always put the directory in the sudo line?

Comment: Have you read my answer? :/ I feel that it should answer this exact question and I'm not sure how to phrase it if it's not enough.

Comment: sorry. I got ahead of myself. Using the export line worked, but won't this screw up anything other than running mysql commands? Do I have to undo this when I'm finished?

Comment: No, because the export line only adds a directory to the path. All the previous ones are still there. You don't need to undo anything.

Comment: I'm trying to add this permanently as you suggested in your second example.  What home directory are you referring to? I don't see a .profile file in my ~/myname directory.  Or did you mean to create a file called .profile?

Comment: Yes @StuartKuredjian, create it if it doesn't exist. This is what the suggested command will do anyways.

Comment: I used text editor to create a file called .profile, confirmed that I want to create a system file and I pasted what you have above into the file.  I saved it, opened a new shell and tried using mysql, but it still comes back with `-bash: mysql: command not fouind`  what am I missing?

Comment: Does `echo $PATH` contain `/usr/local/mysql/bin`, and is `mysql` in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`? Did you create the `.profile` in your home (~) directory?

Comment: (1) Sorry I don't know what this means: "'Does 'echo $PATH' contain '/usr/local/mysql/bin'"  (2) Yes, 'mysql' is in '/usr/local/mysql/bin' (3) Yes, I created the .profile file with 'TextEdit.app' and saved it to '/Users/mycomputername/'.  As a reminder, the first line you gave works, but i have to re-apply it every time I open a new shell.

Comment: For (1), I meant that you have to run `echo $PATH` in a terminal. This is going to tell you (in the form of a list of colon-separated directories) where the terminal looks for programs when you don't use a full path.

Comment: typeing echo $PATH in terminal returns `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Comment: so no.. it doesn't contain '/usr/local/mysql/bin'  and thanks btw zneak.  I didn't understand that at first, but now I do.  Good to know.  So how do I add the mysql/bin path so that 'echo $PATH' contains it?

Comment: I got it, but your instructions kind of send me into a broken terminal. Every time i opened a new shell it would just say `process completed`  I had to launch a new shell and quickly hit ctrl-c to break the command.  Then `rm ~/.profile/` to delete the file.  The proper text to save to .profile is `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`  Thanks zneak.

Answer (score 6):

I had this kind of problem as well. I resolved the issues like:-

1. go to the directory cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/
2. put this command ./mysql -u root -p;
3. it will ask you password the root password you get at the time of installation. that way you will get your mysql connected to the database... hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

unless I'm missing something here, I believe you can just install mump and also run MySQL workbench. and you won't have to deal with a lot of these issues.